# What is the best practice to get data from a table with relations - C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a library project designed with the layered architecture

Currently, I am working on the listing page. I will list the books in my library(The books will be listed only once. I mean there shouldn't be duplicate books because I have more than one in the library ) and there will be filtering options on this page.

On my data access layer, I have codes like that.

```
public List<Library> GetListWithRelations(Expression<Func<Library, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        using (var db = new LibraryDbContext())
        {               
            return filter == null
                ? db.Set<Library>()
                .Include(x => x.Book)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookAuthor).ThenInclude(y => y.Author)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookCategory).ThenInclude(y => y.Category)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookComment)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookImage)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookStarPoint)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookTranslator).ThenInclude(y => y.Author)
                .Include(x => x.Book.Language)
                .Include(x => x.Book.Publisher)
                .ToList()
                : db.Set<Library>()
                .Where(filter)
                .Include(x => x.Book)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookAuthor).ThenInclude(y => y.Author)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookCategory).ThenInclude(y => y.Category)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookComment)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookImage)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookStarPoint)
                .Include(x => x.Book.BookTranslator).ThenInclude(y => y.Author)
                .Include(x => x.Book.Language)
                .Include(x => x.Book.Publisher)
                .ToList();
        }

    }
```

On my Bussiness layer, I have codes like that.

```
 public virtual List<Library> GetListing(List<Category> categories=null, int authorId = 0, int publisherId = 0, int languageId = 0, int pageSortId = 0)
    {

        var retunData = _LibraryDal.GetListWithRelations(x => x.IsShareable==true 
         && (categories==null ||(x.Book.BookCategory.Any(bc => categories.Select(ci => ci.CategoryId).Contains(bc.CategoryId))))
         && (authorId == 0 || x.Book.BookAuthor.Any(ba => ba.AuthorId == authorId))
         && (publisherId == 0 || x.Book.PublisherId == publisherId)
         && (languageId == 0 || x.Book.LanguageId == languageId)
         ).GroupBy(g => g.Book);
     
    }
```

As you can imagine I will need to display and filter the data in relational tables.

My code works fine like that.

My questions:

- Is it a good idea to use entity includes for relations
- Will it work fine when I have many visitors at the web site
- Should I use SQL Stored Procedure instead
- What is the best practice to handle with relational tables like that

  Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: @Licentia .net Core MVC.

Comment: In my opinion use ADO.net or Dapper for Heavy Joins

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it a good idea to use entity includes for relations?

A: in EF if you set navigation/Relation properties as **virtual** properties  you do not have to Include them. However this feature does not work in EF Core. 
so your only choice is stored procedures or include them as you are doing now. I personally never used stored procedures for this purpose

Q: Will it work fine when I have many visitors at the web site?

A: Yes, just make sure that all your methods are async

Answer (score 1):

bad idea!, why... the name  `GetListWithRelations` is generic, and implies you are planning on using this for more than one responsibility. Simply... the query may work, but its a bad idea... as you will hit performance issues all the way.

Simple example of this... which is still silly, pass no filter... 
how long does it take to load 100 books.

PS even with filter its still problematic design, you need more specific... query's for each scenario. Out of scope for SO, as it depends on your needs..., but I'm just informing you that this is not going to work, unless its for a specific report only, even then this will simply not perform in the real world.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what is your suggestion? Should I use SQL stored procedure or is there some better way you can suggest.?

Comment: you would create container which have the linq needed for the different operations, much like what you have but which only works with the data needed. Like most common, UserRepo.GetbyId(string id) returns a user, with no mapping, you need to do more research...

Comment: I have Repository Pattern in the project for such purposes. I think you misunderstand  my question. I need all the data in the query. The question is how to handle with the query which has alot of relations like that.

Comment: `its` or `it's`?

Comment: ok i see, well that down to preference, which i usually sum up like this... lazy man/ vs non lazy man, its usually a weigh off, based on how critical it is. My PERSONAL preference is; I'm never the lazy man, so i would write the SQL which gives me what you looking for then write the LINQ which matchs, if it can not be down in an OO way, i would then think about how to model the data to be most optimal (performance wise). Where as what you have is pure, lazy man/women approach but that does NOT make it wrong nor not fit for purpose. Again about how much time you want to invest for the outcome.